# OutputStreamWriter only writing one item into file

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

I have used the following code to write elements from an arraylist into a  file, to be retrieved later on using StringTokenizer. It works perfect for 3 other arraylists but somehow for this particular one, it throws an exception when reading with .nextToken() and further troubleshooting with .countTokens() shows that it only has 1 token in the file. The delimiters for both write and read are the same - "," as per the other arraylists as well.

I'm puzzled why it doesnt work the way it should as with the other arrays when I have not changed the code structure.

=================Writing to file==================

```
public static void copy_TimeZonestoFile(ArrayList<AL_TimeZone> timezones, Context context){

    try {

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = context.openFileOutput("TimeZones.dat",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        OutputStreamWriter writerFile = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream);

        int TZsize = timezones.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < TZsize; i++) {
            writerFile.write(
                    timezones.get(i).getRegion() + "," +
                            timezones.get(i).getOffset() + "\n"
            );
        }

        writerFile.flush();
        writerFile.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

==========Reading from file (nested in thread/runnable combo)===========

```
        public void run() {


            if (fileTimeZones.exists()){

                System.out.println("Timezone file exists. Loading.. File size is : " + fileTimeZones.length());
                try{

                    savedTimeZoneList.clear();

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput("TimeZones.dat")));
                    String lineFromTZfile = reader.readLine();
                    while (lineFromTZfile != null ){
                        StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(lineFromTZfile,",");
                        AL_TimeZone timeZone = new AL_TimeZone(token.nextToken(),
                                token.nextToken());

                        savedTimeZoneList.add(timeZone);
                    }


                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

===================Trace======================

```
I/System.out: Timezone file exists. Loading.. File size is : 12373
W/System.err: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)
    at com.cryptotrac.trackerService$1R_loadTimeZones.run(trackerService.java:215)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: What does AL_TimeZone look like and what are the values of  its region and offset fields?

Comment: @Abra from the description I'm pretty sure it's a NoSuchElementException when parsing the second line. But still, good advice.

Comment: the AL_TimeZone is just an ArrayList with 2 String elements. much simpler than the others with a mix of int, double, strings etc.  Have updated the question with the relevant trace.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that this line of your code is causing the `java.util.NoSuchElementException` to be thrown.

```java
AL_TimeZone timeZone = new AL_TimeZone(token.nextToken(), token.nextToken());
```

That probably means that at least one of the lines in file **TimeZones.dat** does not contain precisely two strings separated by a single comma.

This can be easily checked by making sure that the line that you read from the file is a valid line before you try to parse it.

Using method [split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)), of class `java.lang.String`, is preferable to using `StringTokenizer`. Indeed the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) of class `StringTokenizer` states the following.

> StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.

Try the following.

```java
String lineFromTZfile = reader.readLine();
while (lineFromTZfile != null ){
    String[] tokens = lineFromTZfile.split(",");
    if (tokens.length == 2) {
        // valid line, proceed to handle it
    }
    else {
        // optionally handle an invalid line - maybe write it to the app log
    }
    lineFromTZfile = reader.readLine(); // Read next line in file.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this method as well but still got sent to the ELSE route. think the problem really came on during the writing part. Will still replace the StringTokenizer method with this though. Thanks!

Comment: @xv.ch if you would like me to help you debug your code, please edit your question and post the contents of file **TimeZones.dat**. Posting a [mcve] as well may also help me to debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably multiple things wrong, because I'd actually expect you to run into an infinite loop, because you are only reading the first line of the file and then repeatedly parse it.

You should check following things:

- Make sure that you are writing the file correctly. What does the written file exactly contain? Are there new lines at the end of each line?
- Make sure that the data written (in this case, "region" and "offset") never contain a comma, otherwise parsing will break. I expect that there is a very good chance that "region" contains a comma.
- When reading files you always need to assume that the file (format) is broken. For example, assume that `readLine` will return an empty line or something that contains more or less than one comma.

Comment: I've tried using ! as a delimiter as well and still doesnt work. in the region and offset, the only non alphabet characters are  "_","/" and "+". do they affect the StringTokenizer method in anyway? As per the code, the file should be read until the end of the last line in the file. I dont think there's anything wrong with that part since it works in the other 3 arrays using the same code.

Comment: the offset contains "-" & ":" as well.